Ubuntu 24.04 Nvidia drivers
All
Fresh install Ubuntu 24.04 - all work fine - but
'ubuntu-drivers list' -  show me only 535 driver
udevadm hwdb is deprecated. Use systemd-hwdb instead.
udevadm hwdb is deprecated. Use systemd-hwdb instead.
udevadm hwdb is deprecated. Use systemd-hwdb instead.
udevadm hwdb is deprecated. Use systemd-hwdb instead.
nvidia-driver-535, (kernel modules provided by linux-modules-nvidia-535-generic-hwe-24.04)
nvidia-driver-535-open, (kernel modules provided by linux-modules-nvidia-535-open-generic-hwe-24.04)
nvidia-driver-535-server-open, (kernel modules provided by linux-modules-nvidia-535-server-open-generic-hwe-24.04)
nvidia-driver-535-server, (kernel modules provided by linux-modules-nvidia-535-server-generic-hwe-24.04)
'apt search ^nvidia-driver-...$' - show
nvidia-driver-460/noble 470.239.06-0ubuntu2 amd64
Transitional package for nvidia-driver-470
nvidia-driver-465/noble 470.239.06-0ubuntu2 amd64
Transitional package for nvidia-driver-470
nvidia-driver-470/noble 470.239.06-0ubuntu2 amd64
NVIDIA driver metapackage
nvidia-driver-510/noble 525.147.05-0ubuntu2 amd64
Transitional package for nvidia-driver-535
nvidia-driver-515/noble 525.147.05-0ubuntu2 amd64
Transitional package for nvidia-driver-535
nvidia-driver-520/noble 525.147.05-0ubuntu2 amd64
Transitional package for nvidia-driver-535
nvidia-driver-525/noble 525.147.05-0ubuntu2 amd64
NVIDIA driver metapackage (transitional package)
nvidia-driver-530/noble 535.171.04-0ubuntu2 amd64
Transitional package for nvidia-driver-535
nvidia-driver-535/noble,now 535.171.04-0ubuntu2 amd64 [installed]
NVIDIA driver metapackage
nvidia-driver-550/noble 550.67-0ubuntu3 amd64
NVIDIA driver metapackage

Is this bug or feature?


I can see both 535 and 550. What is "bug or feature"?

ubuntu-drivers do not allow me to install the 550 version - only 535. Yes, I can install   through apt - but GUI, after that shows me - no driver in use and proposes reinstalling 535

Well, not all Nvidia cards can use all Nvidia drivers. Some cards would be too old, and need an older driver. New cards would usually need a newer driver. Nvidia drops support after 10 years or so. I don't know what the card is in your case, but, apparently, 550 is too new.

This is a bug.  Perhaps related to launchpad 2037004.  lsmod might even show the nvidia driver in use (after manual install of the 550), but nvidia-settings seem not to see it, and neither  ubuntu-drivers nor Software&Updates/AdditionalDrivers show any beyond 535, even with a RTX3080 Nvidia card. System tested was a persistent ISO boot, so pretty vanilla.

LInk to bug. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-drivers-common/+bug/2037004 best to say it applies to you, as more that complain the sooner the fix.

See the context by Timo Aaltonen given on https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-graphics-drivers-550/+bug/2061830
Looks like because the 550 series Nvidia drivers couldn't be tested during 24.04 beta testing, for now they are only being shown as available for hardware that is exclusively supported by those drivers - for all others, 535 is the newest driver series that will be shown until the Ubuntu team has tested and migrated over to 550 by default.

udevadm hwdb is deprecated. Use systemd-hwdb instead.
This notification is because you still are using udevadm-hwdb you should change it to systemd-hwdb
sudo nano /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/UbuntuDrivers/detect.py
Ctrl + W
type udevadm

change the udevadm to systemd in the part that I highlighted
try:
    out = subprocess.check_output(['systemd-hwdb', 'query', alias],
                                  universal_newlines=True)
except (OSError, subprocess.CalledProcessError) as e:
    logging.debug('_get_db_name(%s, %s): systemd-hwdb failed: %s', syspath, alias, str(e))
    return (None, None)



What ever that example is all I get is an error from it. As well if it is text it needs to be in the answer.

Thank you, changed but only removed message "udevadm hwdb is deprecated. Use systemd-hwdb instead."

yes i see after i change to systemd i can found my nvidia driver right no im use 555 version on my gtx

If there is still an error when changing the code, I suggest you delete the old detect.py, replace it with the new one https://github.com/canonical/ubuntu-drivers-common/blob/master/UbuntuDrivers/detect.py

Replaced. Same result.

If I replace I obtain another error systemd-hwdb: unrecognized option '--test=pci:..... 24.04.1 LTS

replace the line exactly as shown i.e. remove the --test flag, and just include 'query' and alias as the other two parameters in the array
