Ubuntu 24.04 does not boot
I have a dell G15 5530 laptop. I dual boot it with Ubuntu 24.04 by watching some of the youtbube videos. When trying to boot into Ubuntu it freezes and I am not able to do anything whereas Windows works well.
I have kept the storage option to AHCI and Safe boot is also disabled.
Can anyone help me with this?

Does it have nVidia? Did you install choosing the optional restricted extra drivers? If not, can you boot to grub menu? Escape key just after Dell logo. And boot recovery mode? or second line in grub menu. From there inn terminal with Internet enabled, you can install nVidia drivers. Or recovery mode may show other issues. Install instructions server or terminal
https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/nvidia-drivers-installation

On running sudo ubuntu-drivers install I got the below message 5 times
drivers already installed.
udevadm hwdb is deprecated. Use systemd-hwdb instead

Yes it has nVidia.While installation I have chosen Extended selection & I have selected Install third party software for graphics & wifi.
Now in safe boot On running sudo ubuntu-drivers install I got the below message 5 times
drivers already installed.
udevadm hwdb is deprecated. Use systemd-hwdb instead

Seems to be a bug. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1511919/ubuntu-24-04-nvidia-drivers & https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-drivers-common/+bug/2037004

I have removed the Ubuntu completely and reinstalled it again while installing I installed without graphics & wifi. Now I am not facing the problem that I am earlier facing .
Thanks @oldfred
